# Can I connect a Unity program to node.js server via socket.io and JavaScript, and if yes how?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unity-game-engine, socket.io

I would like to know if it's possible to connect to a node.js socket.io server from a Unity program. I know we can code with JavaScript inside unity but do Unity has the capabilities of a browser to like transfert data with socket.io? And if yes, how would i do that?

This line of code here allow my web page to connect to socket.io:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:6613');
```

Will it be that easy to do with in Unity and if yes, what am I waiting for?

Comment: Cough, cough, [Google](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/socket.io-unity)

Comment: there is a Unity3D solution with FM WebSocket. youtube demo: https://youtu.be/2oxDz_wsDkE

Comment: I wish you a quick recovery from that coughing disease Sir Hellium. XD

Comment: This question most certainly has nothing to do with [tag:unityscript]

Comment: There is nothing mentioning unityscript in the question nor in the tags...

Answer (score 0):

The link in the comments answered my question. I guess I can't mark my own answer as having solved the problem since it wouldn't be honest, I'd rather not obtain reputation points I didn't earn.